# How to display img from a server in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova

I want to display an image from a server, my function is this :

```
$scope.getImage = function() {

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://url.com/provawp/api/user/get_avatar/?user_id=1&type=full'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            var img=data.avatar;
            var element = $('<div>').html(img);
            var source = element.find('img').attr("src");
            return source;
            console.log("immagine" + source);

         }).
         error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

             console.log("errore avatar");
         });
     }
```

I retrieve my img and then I want to display to my html :

```
   <ons-list-item  class="list-item-container">
      <div class="list-item-left">
        <img ng-src="{{getImage()}}" class="avator">
      </div>
      <div class="list-item-right">
        <div class="list-item-content">
          <div class="name">{{post.author.name}}</div>
          <span class="desc">{{formatDate(post.date)  |  date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}         </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>
```

obviously there is a controller in the page; When I run my log error is this :

Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

my Json data is this :

```
  {"status":"ok","avatar":"<img src=\"http:\/\/url.com\/provawp\/wp- content\/uploads\/2015\/06\/rest5b-150x150.jpg\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" alt=\"admin\" class=\"avatar avatar-150 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-150 alignnone photo\" \/>"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling a function inside `ng-src` attribute with `{{}}` interpolation directive and load image `URL` through ajax wouldn't make sense. As in each `digest` cycle that `$http` call going to get call & causing below error

> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.
>   Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

To avoid such bug assign the value received by ajax inside some scope variable & bind that scope variable inside `ng-src` attribute.

Call `getImage` method on controller load would be an better idea to have it.

**Markup**

```
<img ng-src="{{myImage}}" class="avator">
```

**Code**

```
$scope.getImage = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://url.com/provawp/api/user/get_avatar/?user_id=1&type=full'
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.myImage = data.avatar;
        //return source; //no need to return data
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("errore avatar");
    });
};
$scope.getImage(); //call this from the controller init.
```

Comment: Can you suggest me how ?

Comment: Sorry, but I need to load different user avatar and I need previous function don't think? How can resolve this ?

Comment: @pinostack I don't understand your concern..could you please elaborate it?

Comment: yes sure, I have ng-repeat post in posts and for each post I want to retrieve his avatar; I thought to call a function getImage(post.author.id) and retrieve his avatar; do you understand ?

Comment: @pinostack I got what you are saying..could you open new question for the same.?